# Torsion subgroup combined with normal subgroup!

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, abelian-groups

**Exercise:**

> α) Show that in an abelian group G the set T of its elements with finite order is a subgroup of G (torsion subgroup).
>
> β) Consider if T is a normal subgroup of group G.

I am sorry that  I don't appose any attempt but I don't know even how to start.
Any help or thorough solution would be precious for me as I need to clear my mind on this type of problems.

Comment: Well, what is there to prove?  In order to show a subset is a  subgroup we need to confirm that the identity is in the subset, that the subset is closed under multiplication, and that the inverse of an element in the subset is also in the subset.  Can you show any of those?

Comment: Note:  I don't understand the second question.  The group $G$ is abelian, is it not?

Comment: @lulu yes its an abelian group!

Comment: Ok...but any subgroup of an abelian group is normal (trivially).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**!

For α), if $g$ has order $r$, $h$ has order $s$, consider $(gh)^{rs}$.

For β), if the group is commutative, any subgroup is normal, so there's nothing to prove. However, there exist non-commutative groups for which the torsion elements *are* a subgroup, viz. nilpotent groups, but it is very technical.

*Added*:

However, if you *know* that, for some reason,  the set $T$ of torsion elements in a (not necessarily abelian) group is a subgroup, then it is a normal subgroup.

Actually, it is even more: recall that a normal subgroup is a subgroup which is invariant by *inner automorphisms* of the group. Actually, $T$ is invariant by every *endomorphism* of the group, i.e. it is a *fully characteristic subgroup*.

Indeed, if $g\in T$, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $g^n=e$. Let  $u$ be any endomorphism of $G$, we have: $$\bigl(u(g)\bigr)^n=u(g^n)= e^n=e,\;\text{ so }\enspace u(g)\in T.$$

Comment: thanks for your answer!I think that it's not a theoritical question.Maybe it wants the technical way.That's bad for me lol!

Comment: @ParisK.Patsogiannis: I think the second question  is really this: if $T$ is a subgroup, show it is a *normal* subgroup. I've added a proof of  this.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment!That is very helpful